Staging ground edit did not make it to the published question
This question from staging ground did not match the one that got published:
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78626946
The author made an edit I suggested to remove a request for advice on a community for learning the library they were working with.
However when I click the link in the to the published question, Strange issue with hammerspoon window movement
The edit they made is not present, I assume something went wrong. But the edit and the timestamp of the post seem to be same.
I am unsure if this is a bug. I have edit the published question to match the change to the staging ground that they intended to apply.

I suspect this is the same problem as this report. Any action that edits + graduates doesn't apply the edit first.

Based on the question's timeline, the edit and graduation were simultaneous, so this indeed sounds like the same problem.  I've added a comment there linking back to here with a note that this also applies to edits from the asker.  Thanks for the additional report!
